# MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem not releasing mapViewController

Tags: memory-leaks, mapkit

Just came across a bug in MapKit, wanted to see what the community is experiencing. When adding a MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem to a UIToolBar, I'm seeing the map is not releasing from memory when switching to another viewController (though I see the dealloc is firing).

Can anyone confirm they are seeing this behavior? My testing shows the map releases properly if I do not add MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem. Using iOS7, testing with Instruments/Leaks.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *userTrackingBarButtonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView];
        [userTrackingBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(track:)];

        UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

        [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceBarButton, userTrackingBarButtonItem, flexibleSpaceBarButton, nil] animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
     }
```

Comment: This is an open Apple Bug.

Answer (score 1):

MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem and the MKMapView each hold strong references to each other, resulting in a circular retain. This appears to be a bug in MapKit itself, and it's still present in iOS 7.1.

A solution is to add a dealloc to your view controller that contains the MapView:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    userTrackingBarButtonItem.mapView = nil; // Circular reference bug workaround
}
```